# Google Script to change Cell Value Based On Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

Can someone please help me. I have not used scripts before but it looks like I am going to have to for this particular problem.

Spreadsheet 1 Column C queries from Spreadsheet 2 and is not editable.

Spreadsheet 1 Column B is editable and it's data is returned back to SH 2.

Spreadsheet 1 - If data on Column C changes to blank , I want Column B to become blank as well but still keep the data validation list for future selections.

**Before Data Removed**
[image]

**Problem - CELL SHOULD CLEAR**
[image]

**Desired Outcome - CELL IS CLEAR!**
[image]

Comment: You could try adding conditional formatting that colors the B column text in blanc when the C one is empty, so it would look like it is empty too... Elsewise if you B column data is not a formula, you'll have to make a script

Comment: You can create script with [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) trigger, then check if edited range is C column and if value is empty, then clear B value